# How do I filter a ng-repeat by a boolean attribute in Angular.Dart?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

Each `space` is an object with a boolean attribute called `open`, and I'm putting them into two lists. In this case, I have two of them, one is `true` and one is `false`. When the list renders at all, both items are in the open list. Here's what I've tried:

```
ng-repeat="space in ctrl.manager.spaces | filter:open"
ng-repeat="space in ctrl.manager.spaces | filter:!open"
```

and

```
ng-repeat="space in ctrl.manager.spaces | filter:open:true"
ng-repeat="space in ctrl.manager.spaces | filter:open:false"
```

and

```
ng-repeat="space in ctrl.manager.spaces | filter:{'open':true}"
ng-repeat="space in ctrl.manager.spaces | filter:{'open':false}"
```

`{{space.open}}` confirms that one is `true` and one is `false`.

Comment: I just tried it using a predicate function in my controller, but the problem there is that the lists are not rerendered when the value changes, presumably because Angular doesn't know what to observe (it's hidden in the function).

Comment: Although rendering the field as a test using my predicate function, {{ctrl.isOpen(space)}}, does update just fine.

Comment: Have you tried filter:{space.open:true}?

Comment: That throws an exception -- it's expecting a colon, not a dot. If I quote `space.open`, it complains that `Space` doesn't have a `space` method, but as in the original post, `'open'` doesn't work.

Comment: filter:{open:true} : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17655837/ng-repeat-filter-on-boolean

Comment: No, that just gives me no entries. That link is to an AngularJS question, btw. I don't know how much they're supposed to be compatible.

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to apply this filter is

```
ng-repeat="item in items | filter: {open: 'true'}
ng-repeat="item in items | filter: {open: '!true'}
```

(put the `'true'` in quotes)