# Angular 1.3 filter list of objects with array attribute

Tags: arrays, angularjs, filter, nested

I hope someone can help me. 
For my current project in angular 1.3 I'm using this list:

```
$scope.myList = [{
  id: "obj1",
  content: [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'attr 1'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'attr 2'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'attr 3'
  }]
}, {
  id: "obj2",
  content: [{
    id: 4,
    name: 'attr 4'
  }, {
    id: 5,
    name: 'attr 5'
  }, {
    id: 6,
    name: 'attr 6'
  }]
}, {
  id: "obj3",
  content: [{
    id: 7,
    name: 'attr 7'
  }, {
    id: 8,
    name: 'attr 8'
  }, {
    id: 9,
    name: 'attr 9'
  }]
}];
```

I would like to get the object which has the id X in the content array.

I used this ng-repeat:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in myList | filter: {content: [{id:1}]}">
    {{item}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

When I use id:1, id:4 or id:7 it works, but not for the other ids...

Has anyone any ideas?

**Edit**

I FINALLY found out what caused the problem, I was using angular 1.3.0. After upgrading to 1.3.11 it worked!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter based on nested properties like so:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in myList | filter: {content: {id: '1'}}">
   {{item}}
</li>
```

It's important to note that the "object" (that has the id X) you'll get will be at the `item` level.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, but it isn't working because 'content' contains an array of objects. If the object 'content' had a property 'id' your are totally right...

Comment: @user2246413, works fine for me with your (slightly modified for illustration) data: http://plnkr.co/edit/katQANxYUVmWvu8yeltU?p=preview

Comment: @user2246413, did you try it with how I showed in the plunker?

Comment: I FINALLY found out what caused the problem, I was using angular 1.3.0. After upgrading to 1.3.11 it worked!!