# custom filter on angular with an object nested inside a nested array

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I have an array with the name of `sports`, json:

```
 [
  {
    "id": 26,
    "name": "LIVE Betting",
    "priority": 0,
    "leagues": []
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "name": "NBA",
    "priority": 3,
    "leagues": [
      {
        "id": 5932,
        "parent": 1000,
        "name": "NBA",
        "sport": {
          "id": 8,
          "name": "NBA"
        },
        "lineType": "G",
        "priority": [
          1,
          3
        ],
        "part": "0"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 24,
    "name": "College Basketball",
    "priority": 4,
    "leagues": [
      {
        "id": 2599,
        "parent": 1000,
        "name": "NCAA BASKETBALL",
        "sport": {
          "id": 24,
          "name": "College Basketball"
        },
        "lineType": "G",
        "priority": [
          0,
          4
        ],
        "part": "0"
      },
      {
        "id": 2631,
        "parent": 1000,
        "name": "NCAA BASKETBALL ADDED GAMES",
        "sport": {
          "id": 24,
          "name": "College Basketball"
        },
        "lineType": "G",
        "priority": [
          1,
          4
        ],
        "part": "0"
      },
      ...
```

within that array you can see another with the name of `"leagues": [{...}]` which contains an object, my filter is searching fine thru the top array which is `sports` but once I try to find thru the `"name"` within `leagues` array then my app shows up a message that the filter is empty.

```
<input type="search" ng-model="query">

<div ng-repeat="sport in sportsFilter = (sports | filter:query)">
        <!--this array works fine-->
        <strong>{{sport.name}}</strong>
      </div>
      <div ng-repeat="league in sport.leagues">
        <!--this one not works at all-->
        {{league.name}}
      </div>
</div>
```

I've been trying all the ways already, with a `resolve`, with different models, etc and actually I just realized that I need a custom filter so I would like you to give me a hand because I do not where to start from with it.

or is there any easier way ?

Comment: You want to use the same `query` to search objects in `leagues` array? Do you want to match any property of `leagues`?

Comment: yes, the same query and the property name.

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28160037/968155

Comment: i didn't get that with my code: I have it this way on mine ```ng-repeat="league in sport.leagues | filter: {leagues: {name: query}}``` and still not working,also remember that I have 2 ```ng-repeat``` working with the same ```ng-model='query'```

Comment: actually I have it working this way ```ng-repeat="sport in sportsFilter = ( sports | filter: {leagues: [{name:query}]} )"``` but now my issue is with the ```sports``` array, I need to do something like: ```ng-repeat="sport in sportsFilter = ( sports | filter: {leagues: [{name:query}]} | filter:query)"``` but still not working

Comment: Your issue here is that you are trying to show either a matching `sport.name` and all of its matching and non-matching `leagues`, OR a non-matching `sport.name` and only its matching `leagues`. This cannot be done with a predicate filter like that. You need to create a filter function. Oh, and you should really get into a habit of never saying "not working". What's not working? Does it behave incorrectly (how?), throws an error (what error), set your house on fire (call the fire department)...

Comment: you look like my dad haha my thank you again. Can you give me an idea of how to create that function?