# why my custom filter is not working?

Tags: angularjs

**app.js**

```
angular.module('capilleira.clickAndGambleMobile', [
 'capilleira.clickAndGambleMobile.filters'
)]
```

**filter.js**

```
angular.module('capilleira.clickAndGambleMobile.filters', [])
  .filter('sportsFiltered', function() {
    return function(output) {

      return alert('I AM THE FILTER');

    }
  });
```

**whatever.html**

```
 <!--HERE IS THE NG-MODEL-->
 <input type="text" ng-model="sportsFiltered">


<div ng-repeat="sport in sportsFilter = (sports | filter:sportsFiltered)">
  {{sport.name}}
</div>


<div ng-repeat="league in sport.leagues | filter: {leagues: [{'name':sportsFiltered}]}}">
  {{league.name}}
</div>
```

why this filter is not doing the `alert` ? or what can I do to realize that the filter is working or not ?

Comment: typo in app.js? `)]` --> `])` ?

Comment: I just removed all that part and the alert is not showing yet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the filter wrongly, you have created an entire filter so you should use it directly as

```
sports | sportsFiltered
```

instead of

```
sports | filter:sportsFiltered
```

When you use `(sports | filter:sportsFiltered)` it is considered to be a filter(built in filter) `comparator` function that you can set up and it will just run that function (on the scope) and based on truthy/falsy value it will decide on whether to show that item or not. So eventually it does not even consider the actual filter you have created.

> {{ filter_expression | filter : expression : comparator}}

Comment: great because now the alert shows up but what do I put on my ```input ng-model=" ? "```

Comment: ng-model? where is it

Comment: ngmodel will just be an object, not your filter name. and the object can be structured according to your datastructure, or the structure can be set in the filter expression as well whichyou are doing. But the array `[` thing will not work

Comment: what do mean will not work ? I mean, all I have is an input search which has to look for content in an array, if I put ```sports | sportsFiltered``` how my will know that I trying to search something something with the ```sportsFiltered``` filter ? sorry bro my not clear for me yet and look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28349584/custom-filter-on-angular-with-an-object-nested-inside-a-nested-array maybe you could help me there. is regarding the same filter.

Comment: I told you to see that question for you to understand the root of the issue. thanks anyways